# why tuple assignment in function arguments doesn't work in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, iterable-unpacking

In Python3 the following code doesn't work anymore:

```
def function((a, (b, c))):
  pass
```

Why was it removed? What's the reason?

Comment: See [PEP 3113](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer by reading [PEP 3113](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). In short words: There were more troubles in keeping the tuple parameter unpacking than removing it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your participation. You already included an essential point of the article in your answer, but could you please add a few reasons for the removal? In case the link dies or changes, future users will still be able to learn something from your answer :)

Comment: Rather than duplicate the information in the PEP, I think a link to an authoritative source is better.  PEPs will persist for a good long while, and they have all of the information needed.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome 1337. StackOverflow helped me many. uncountable times so I wanted to start giving sth. back! I agree with Ned Batchelder, it would be unnecessary duplication of information and for me it would be difficult to sum up the reasons for the removal in a short abstract that suits a short answer on StackOverflow.